# Google Earth Engine: Proper syntax for verifying contents of coordinates list within dictionary value

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api

Quick question here: How can I get the expected return true value at line 15, by confirming a sample location is indeed within the value-list of a specified dictionary key?

```
// Goal: Verify if extracted metadata info matches to a target list

var sampleDate = "2013-03-28";
var sampleLocation = ee.Geometry.Point(-82.1446,29.7842);

var list = [(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.1246,27.7342)), (ee.Geometry.Point(-82.1446,29.7842)), (ee.Geometry.Point(-72.1446,24.7842))];
print(ee.List(list).contains(sampleLocation)); // Works!

var dict = ee.Dictionary({
  '2013-03-28': [(ee.Geometry.Point(-83.1246,27.7342)), (ee.Geometry.Point(-82.1446,29.7842)), (ee.Geometry.Point(-72.1446,24.7842))], // Middle entry being the one to match to
  '2014-03-28': [(ee.Geometry.Point(-84.1246,29.7342)), (ee.Geometry.Point(-87.1446,24.7842))],
  '2015-03-28': [(ee.Geometry.Point(-82.1246,26.7342)), (ee.Geometry.Point(-89.1446,23.7842))]
});

print(ee.List.(dict.get(sampleDate)).contains(sampleLocation)); // Doesn't work... How can I verify if location is within list of dictionary key?
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9af27164097524a6c7eb3779e9853a43

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the dictionary values because dictionaries are a different construct type than lists. So if you change your print statement it should be something like this:

```
print(dict.values().flatten().contains(sampleLocation))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/df20c20a107f64824fb396570dd5394a

-- EDIT
checking for the keys (your dates) has a similar approach:

```
print(dict.keys().contains(sampleDate))
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1a3b056039cf19c3498293a153f028f4

-- EDIT 2
now with a filter on date followed by a filter on location:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/2fd672397ad7ad539ae58177e91dd143

Comment: That's very neat to see, thanks. However, is there a way to incorporate the sampleDate part? Some data I'd want filtered out may be extracted at the right site, but the wrong day, so I'd need to verify my extracted info has a match on both criteria.

Comment: I updated the answer, you can verify for the keys. If you want to use this approach you'd have to build a filter (ee.Filter.eq()) that first checks on the sampledate. But that depends on how you'd want to approach it I guess.

Comment: Well, I need to verify for first key match and then value match within that key, at once in one line. The true value check would have to involve both sampleDate and sampleLocation together. Filtering could help do that though? Would it still just all go in one line? Or would I be filtering and copying the dictionary before doing the check? Not having much luck so far but I'll keep trying.

Comment: Your original question was: 
'// Doesn't work... How can I verify if location is within list of dictionary key?'
So that has been answered. If you want additional information to ask a new question, also fair for the person who provided to effort to answer your question. Based on this information i'm guessing you want to find EXACT matches for locations and dates. Not sure if this is possible in one line of code, I'll give one more suggestion in the script. But else I recommend asking a new question and specifying more clearly your desired output...